# Is this mysql connector for dotnet bug or my fault?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

This is my code
Conntction_String is Returned mysql connection info
Table_Name string is Returned Table name From Tables

This codes Select from table and Where active columns value is 1
mysql connect is successful, but
mysqldataadapter fill data in ds(dataset) failed.

This link is same as my case.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259

and Keynotfoundexception...

nothing utf8mb3 charset in target database. alse Database default charset is utf8mb4
all tables setting utf8mb4 or settings utf16 charset.

I trying mysql.data.dll file newer version updated and Previous version installed
but still not solved this problem.

mysql version is 10.10.2
mysql connector for dotnet version is 8.0.22

```
    public class SQL_Comm
    {
        public bool Select_Check_Activate(int Tbl_Pram)
        {
            //DataSet ds = null;
            string sql = "";
            string Equip, Line, Sensor = "";
            string Table_Name = Tables(Tbl_Pram); //Enum.GetName(string, typeof(Tables), Tbl_Pram);
            DataSet ds = null;
            bool is_activate = false;
            MySqlCommand Cmd;

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(Connection_String());
                if (Conn != null) Conn.Open();
                if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open && Table_Name != "")
                {
                    sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM " + Table_Name + " WHERE active = '1'");
                    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
                    adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(ds, Table_Name);
                    foreach(var Table_Contents in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {

                    }
                }
                Conn.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return is_activate;
        }
    }
```

Exception Thrown info ⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇

```
2023-02-24 00:00:10,249\[DEBUG\]/DB Selection Error : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 지정한 키가 사전에 없습니다. (The given key was not present in the dictionary)
위치: System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
위치: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2.get_Item(TKey key)
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField\[\] columns)
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols)
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()
위치: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
위치: System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable\[\] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
위치: System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
위치: System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

1. mysql connector(mysql.data.dll) version updated 6.10.7 ~ 8.0.22 (available all nuget package)
2. mysql server updated newer version
3. set charset utf8mb4 in database and all tables(also trying utf16)
4. dotnet framework version update

Comment: VBA is the language used inside MS Office applications. Clearly this is not VBA code. It is also not VB or VBS or VB.Net. Tag spamming is a very good way to get your question closed or downvoted very quickly. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should only be used when they actually apply to your question. If you need more information, see the [help] pages.

Comment: Did you try to set the character set explicitly in the connection string?

Comment: @Haminteu Yes, charset setting collectly but same exception thrown

Comment: Column ``active`` not exists in table ``table_name``?

Comment: @ValNik No, Already exist target table. also "active" lower latter correctly.
And correctly working query in Heidi sql

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259 is about a `NotSupportedException`. You're getting a `KeyNotFoundException`. This is possibly a different problem, with a different solution. It would be helpful if you could debug it and find out _what_ key wasn't found.

Comment: If https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259 is the problem you're running into, then it's fixed in v8.0.30. You need to update to at least that version. Or you could switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ (disclaimer: lead author) which doesn't have this bug in any version.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I trying 8.0.30 version or higher(Available all nuget package version). but same errors.